# Will a URL always create security scoped bookmarks with exactly the same byte pattern?

Tags: macos, nsurl, foundation, appstore-sandbox, security-scoped-bookmarks

I want to maintain a list of folders, in a sandboxed Mac app.  To do that, I need to make a security-scoped bookmark, using `url.bookmarkData()`.

Is it guaranteed that the `Data` returned by this method is always the same byte pattern, for a given file URL?

That is, can I take a new `url.bookmarkData()` and test if a `[Data]` list contains a security-scoped bookmark for the same URL, by just checking the Data instances?  Or do I need to resolve each `Data` into a `URL` and compare those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

Make a sandboxed Mac app.  Then:

1. Use FileManager's `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` to get the `.downloadsFolder`, and then run it through `destinationOfSymbolicLink(atPath:)` to get a URL with a path like `"/Users/me/Downloads"`
2. Use NSOpenPanel to ask the user for a file, and choose your Downloads folder.  You'll get a URL with a path like `"/Users/me/Downloads"`

Call `.bookmarkData()` on the URLs in #1 and #2.  The `Data`s you get aren't even the same length.